ガチ感 what does it mean?
The character is explaining is band was fairly popular and he explains
それはキヨシくんがあったからで!
Then his friend thinks this in his mind:
あのバンドのボーカルをくんづけで呼ぶとはなんというガチ感
he's show to be angry for further context
I'm not sure, what is the meaning of なんというガチ感 here? Is he saying he's really serious in using the kun with the band vocalist?

Looks like you may have missed how this とは is used. This statement expresses surprise about "あのバンドのボーカルをくんづけで呼ぶ".

なんというX is a common pattern to express "What an X!".
ガチ is a slang term that roughly means "serious", "hardcore", or "professional" (as opposed to casual, amateur, etc). It implies that someone is intensely committed to something.
X感 is an informal suffix that conveys a mood like "X-ishness" or "sense/aura/vibe of X".

So なんというガチ感 indicates that the speaker perceived a sense of serious enthusiasm (if he is a fan) or professionalism (if he is also a musician) in the way he uses the expression キヨシくん. くん is a common suffix in the context of young male idols, but if it's a heavy/visual-kei rock band, it might indeed be unusual for ordinary casual fans to address the vocalist with くん.

あのバンドのボーカルをくんづけで呼ぶとはなんというガチ感
Calling the vocalist of that band with kun—what a hardcore vibe!

